# Why the lock inside AsyncLock does not block the thread?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, locking, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to understand how the [AsyncLock](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/AsyncLock.md) works.

First of all, here's a snippet to prove that it actually works:

```
var l = new AsyncLock();
var tasks = new List<Task>();
while (true)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
    var i = tasks.Count + 1;
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] Acquiring lock ...");
        using (await l.LockAsync())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] Lock acquired");
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }
    }));
}
```

By "works" I mean that you can run as many tasks as you want (by hitting Enter) and the number of threads doesn't grow. If you replace it with traditional `lock`, you'll see that the new threads are started, which is what we try to avoid.

**But the first thing you see in the source code is... the [lock](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncLock.cs#L102)**

Can somebody please explain me how this works, why it doesn't block, and what am I missing here?

Comment: This question is a little unclear, Does the above code work or not, and can you show the code that does work

Comment: Yes, it works, but I don't understand why.

Comment: by "works" I mean it re-uses threads. But the `lock` keyword should block threads (it's easy to prove it in the same example).

Comment: *"re-uses threads"* is of no concern, `Task` does not equal thread. However, more precisely *"The lock statement acquires the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executes a statement block, and then releases the lock. While a lock is held, the thread that holds the lock can again acquire and release the lock. Any other thread is blocked from acquiring the lock and waits until the lock is released."*

Comment: Yes, tasks are mapped to threads, but since they all try to acquire the same lock, all scheduler's threads should be blocked and each new task should start a new thread after a delay. I've just tried it and it is true for a simple lock operation. But for some reason the lock inside `AsyncLock` behaves differently, or I'm missing something.

Comment: @astef could you please clarify your understanding of `lock(x){return 1;}` when multiple threads run the same code? In particular why you expect this usage of `lock` to block many threads?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Because the `lock` is a sugar for `Monitor` which is a system-level primitive which blocks the thread. When you `lock` inside a `Task`, the underlying thread is blocked and the `TaskScheduler` has to start another thread to be able to run new `Tasks`.

Comment: @astef you've posted answer saying that there will be no contention/new threads because that particular  lock is very short lived (which makes perfect sense)... I'm confused why you say `lock(x){return 1;}` will cause threads to pile up as it is slightly simplified version of the code you've linked too... Or you are talking about some general case? or you think `lock` inside task would behave differently?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It would cause threads to pile up if there will be no return which is releasing the lock. Somehow I was unable to understand the fact that the `lock` is released. There's still theoretical chance that the first task will be veeery slow in the lock section and someone who is creating other tasks will be veeery fast and threadpool will be exhausted, but it is not practical concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can somebody please explain me how this works, why it doesn't block, and what am I missing here?

The short answer is that `lock` is just an internal mechanism used to guarantee thread safety. The `lock` is never exposed in any way, and there's no way for any thread to hold that lock for any real amount of time. In this way, it's similar to the locks used internally by various concurrent collections.

There is an alternate approach that uses lock-free programming, but I have found lock-free programming to be extremely difficult to write, read, and maintain. A great example of this (which is sadly not online) was a bunch of Dr. Dobb's articles in the late '90s, each one trying to out-do the last with a better lock-free queue implementation. It turns out they were all faulty - in some cases, the bugs took more than a decade to find.

For my own code, I do not use lock-free programming, except where the correctness of the code is trivially obvious.

---

As far as the async lock vs lock concepts, I'm going to take a stab at explaining this. There's a feeling I get that I have only felt when working with asynchronous coordination primitives. It's something I've thought a lot about writing a blog post on, but I don't have the right words to make it understandable. That said, here goes...

Asynchronous coordination primitives exist on a completely different plane than normal coordination primitives. Synchronous primitives block threads and signal threads. Asynchronous primitives just work on plain objects; the blocking or signaling is just "by convention".

So, with a normal `lock`, the calling code *must* take the lock immediately. But with an asynchronous "lock", the attempted lock is just a request, just an object. The calling code doesn't even need to `await` it. It's possible to request *several* locks and `await` them all together with `Task.WhenAll`. Or even combine them with other things; code can do crazy things like (a)wait for two locks to both be free *or* for a signal (like `AsyncManualResetEvent`) to be sent, and then cancel the lock requests if the signal comes in first.

From a thread perspective, it's kinda-sorta like user-mode thread scheduling. There's also some similarities to cooperative multitasking (as opposed to preemptive). But overall, the asynchronous primitives are "lifted" to a different plane, where one works only with objects and blocks of code, not threads.

Answer (score 1):

The [lock inside `AsyncLock`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncLock.cs#L102) is beeing released very quickly. Each task which tries to acquire `AsyncLock`, successfully acquires it's internal `lock` and the actual locking logic is done with a queue.

Answer (score 1):

By wrapping `LockAsync()` within `using` block, the lock is being released when the block ends since `LockAsync` returns a disposable object `Key` which will be disposed at the end of the `using` block, and upon disposing the lock will be released. see https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncLock.cs#L182-L185