# Why sequential call of AsyncLock within same (UI) thread doesn't work same way as for different threads (like via Task.Run)?

Tags: c#, async-await, locking

*Partially, this question has a bit of similarity with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57104135/why-the-lock-inside-asynclock-does-not-block-the-thread), but as another one is not properly asked (and not fully asked) I am trying to ask it in general, so this question can not be considered as a duplication.*

The question is about understanding of **how AsyncLock actually works**. (In this context I am referring to [Neosmart.AsyncLock](https://github.com/neosmart/AsyncLock) library, however, I consider it uses common approach in AsyncLock implementation).

So. For instance, we have a main thread (let it be a UI-thread):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press Esc for exit");

        var lck = new AsyncLock();

        var doJob = new Action(async () =>
        {
            using (await lck.LockAsync())
            {
                // long lasting job
                Console.WriteLine("+++ Job starts");
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                Console.WriteLine("--- Job finished");
            }
        });

        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            doJob();
        }
    }
```

so, sequental pressing of Enter starts `doJob`every time without waiting until previous job finished.

However, when we change it to:

```
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        doJob();
    });
```

... everything works like a charm, and no new jobs is run until previous finished.

That's clear that async logic is far different than classic `lock(_myLock)` and can't be comparable directly, however, still, **why the first approach doesn't work that way** when the second call of LockAsync would "lock" (again, in async context) the "long lasting job" to start until previous finished.

---

There is actually a practical request of why I need that code to work this way, (and real question is **how I can achieve that with await LockAsync**?):

For example, in my app (for instance, my mobile app), on very launch there is some data I am **starting pre-loading** (this is a common service which needs that data to keep in cache for further use), then, when the UI is started, a **particular page requests the same data** for the UI to appear and asks the same service to load the same data. So, without any custom logic that service **would start two long lasting jobs** to retrieve the same pack of data. *Instead, I want my UI to receive the data from the cache right the data pre-loading finished.*
Like that (an abstract possible scenario):

```
    class MyApp
    {
        string[] _cache = null;
        AsyncLock _lock = new AsyncLock();

        async Task<IEnumerable<string>> LoadData()
        {
            using (await _lock.LockAsync())
            {
                if (_cache == null)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                    _cache = new[] {"one", "two", "three"};
                }
                return _cache;
            }
        }

        void OnAppLaunch()
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        async void OnMyCustomEvent()
        {
            var data = await LoadData();
            // to do something else with the data
        }
    }
```

the problem would be solved if I would change it to `Task.Run(async () => { var data = await LoadData(); })` but it doesn't look like quite clean and nice approach.

Comment: I suspect this is because your lock is thread re-enterant - that is to say, if the thread that attempts to obtain the lock already holds the lock, then it is allowed through. Only different threads will be blocked. When you do `Task.Run()`, a different thread is attempting to obtain the lock each time, so it gets blocked.

Comment: Did you check [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.8) class? It might be good alternative, it exposes asynchronous `WaitAsync` method, and with `initialCount` set to 1, you can achieve desired locking behavior.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, exactly. This is because of "re-entrance", and this is what in the docs of the library mentioned. However, this is why I've created this question here. Why? Why it allows re-entrance? I don't actually need this and this is what creates my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Matthew points out in the comments, `AsyncLock` is reentrant, meaning that if the same thread attempts to take the lock a second time, it recognizes that and allows it to continue. The author of `AsyncLock` wrote a lengthy article about how **reentrance was really the reason he wrote it**: [AsyncLock: an async/await-friendly locking library for C# and .NET](https://neosmart.net/blog/2017/asynclock-an-asyncawait-friendly-locking-library-for-c-and-net/)

It's not a bug; it's a feature.™

After the "Update 5/25/2017" heading, there are code examples demonstrating exactly what you are experiencing here and showing how it is a feature.

Reasons to want reentrance are:

1. If you are just concerned with multiple threads touching the same variable (preventing race conditions), then there is simply no reason to block a thread that already has the lock.
2. It makes recursive functions that use locks easier to write because you don't need to test if you already have the lock. A lack of reentrance support + sloppy recursive coding = deadlock.

If you really want it to not be reentrant, you can use what he says was not appropriate for reentrance: [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim):

```
var lck = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

var doJob = new Action(async () => {

    await lck.WaitAsync();

    try {
        // long lasting job
        Console.WriteLine("+++ Job starts");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        Console.WriteLine("--- Job finished");
    } finally {
        lck.Release();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you omitted for brevity the releasing of the semaphore in a finally block?

Comment: Thanks @GabrielLuci unfortunately I haven't found this article in Google earlier by some reason. So, great you reference that. And yes, in my case SemaphoreSlim is exactly what needed!